# Could I write an Android app to talk with a bluetooth device that already has an app?

Tags: android, bluetooth

A friend of mine has a daughter that is doing a project in school and a Bluetooth thermometer is required.

If I bought a generic Bluetooth device (thermometer or something else) could I potentially write an app to talk with that device?  In this case get the temperature.

I'm just not sure if the Bluetooth device is communicating in some form of messaging that only their app can understand.

Comment: bluetooth is a communications protocol. the act of communication is standardized, but the data that's communicated is arbitrary. e.g. you can undoubtedly pair up to the thermometer, but may not be able to understand what it's telling or you, or even how to tell it to tell you something.

Comment: That is what I figured.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've integrated a number of Bluetooth Low Energy devices into android apps, but not a thermometer. As noted, discovering and connecting to the device is done using standard protocol components, but the data to send/receive is up to the vendor of the device.

The Bluetooth SIG has defined an standard for thermometers, so I would suggest that you try to find a vendor that implements this standard, that way you will know how to access the temperature data once you have connected to the device.

The Bluetooth SIG page is here: https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.health_thermometer.xml

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!